# Unknown process is running at 100% of CPU on two seperate computers

Tags: 18.04, cpu-load

I have two separate computer running Ubuntu 18.04

Both computer have a random unknown process that will take up 100% of two CPU cores. However, it will be gone after I reboot the PC. How do i remove them and make sure that they will run anymore? How do I find out what them? You may see the process in the top two row of the HTOP.

[PC 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CPtWK.png)

[PC 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d84UQ.png)

Comment: Do I understand correctly that this process starts at every boot, but has a different name/command each time?

Comment: In `top`, use "c" and "V" to see its origin. Use F5 in `htop` to switch to tree view.

Comment: Locate the process command name on your filesystem using `sudo find / | grep -i /xxx` where `xxx` is the name you see at right of `top`s output. If it is somewhere under your home directory or in a tmp directory it may be a malware. Try the find the parent of this process in your "process tree."